# Share zend module controllers for use in another module

Tags: php, zend-framework

Let's say I have a User_RegistrationController from with I want to extend in another module like so:

```
class Clinic_RegisterController extends User_RegisterController
```

but I've PHP error for that:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'User_RegisterController' not found /application/modules/clinic/controllers/RegisterController.php on line 4
```

Is there any way to extend a controller from another module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pull your base controller into into a separate library class:

```
class App_Controller_Action_MyController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    // your base controller code here
}
```

Then the controller in module `foo` could be empty:

```
class Foo_MyController extends App_Controller_Action_MyController
{
}
```

while the controller in module `bar` could contain your overrides:

```
class Bar_MyController extends App_Controller_Action_MyController
{
     // override your members/methods
}
```

Don't forget the add `App_` as an `autoloadernamespace`.

Answer (score 1):

The autoloader is just not set up to find controllers from other modules.

If you want to do what you are doing, you can simply add a `require_once` statement above your class definition:

```
require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/user/controllers/RegisterController.php';

class Clinic_RegisterController extends User_RegisterController
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a controller from another module to be extended? This creates a dependency on another module. If there is common code in both controllers use [action helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.writingyourown) in the application layer.

Comment: Well I have whole controller that is resonsible for registration and login of diffrent users, Dont want to duplicate code, but Action Helpers seems bit to small for few actions and methods so I've though inheritance by a controller would be a solution.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the 2nd controller that would duplicate registration/login?

Comment: Beacose i need to seperate things for let say a customer role in one module and things for a let say clinic role in second module, beacose I will be reusing them much. So I dont want to duplicate the code with the actions I will not use.