# How do I reuse and override controller actions across two modules in Zend Framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I have a modular setup of Zend Framework currently with only 2 modules:

```
web
mobile
```

The setup is as under:

```
applications
--modules
----**web**
------controllers
--------IndexController.php
-----------function indexAction(){.......}
-----------function pageAction(){......}
------models
--------Model.php
------views
--------scripts
----------index.phtml
----**mobile**
------controllers
--------IndexController.php
------views
--------scripts
----------index.phtml
```

I want to achieve code reuse in the `IndexController` in `mobile` module, by reusing `indexAction()` and `pageAction()` in `IndexController` of **`web`** module, and also add another method **`paperAction()`** in `**mobile**` module, that's only available to `mobile` module. Is there a way to do this without having the code copied in `IndexController.php` of `web` module in `mobile` module?

Thanks

Comment: will most of the models, etc be the same as well? what are the major differences between your web and mobile modules? Have you considered context switching as an alternative? http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/48

Comment: yeah.. most of the models will be same.. but I need the additional functionality of overriding an existing controller action if required.

Comment: Usually Action Helpers are used for this sort of thing.

Comment: What if I need to stick with this approach? I wanted the modules to have complete flexibility.. They can be independent if needed, but I wanted a lot of code reuse to happen as well.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which method fits your needs, you could either create a base controller that the index controllers from each model will extend from.  In the base controller, define the minimal functionality that you want shared between the two.

Or, make one of the module controllers the master one, by having the other module controller extend from it.

In the first example, you would do something like this:

### application/controllers/IndexBaseController.php

```
<?php
class IndexBaseController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    public function indexAction() {
        // shared code for both modules' indexaction here...
    }

    public function pageAction() {
        // shared code for both modules' pageaction here...
    }
}
```

Then, extend both module controllers from this:

### application/modules/web/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers/IndexBaseController.php';

class Web_IndexController extends IndexBaseController {
    // other actions here, this already contains indexAction and pageAction()
}
```

Then do the same with `mobile/controllers/IndexController.php`.

The other option, is to make one of the controllers (web or mobile) the controller that the other extends from.  See this answer [Share zend module controllers for use in another module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075283/share-zend-module-controllers-for-use-in-another-module/10081200#10081200) for an example of how to do that.  It is similar, you just have to require the correct controller file so you can extend from it.

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can just instantiate your controller  and call their method at any time

```
$web_ctlr=new Web_IndexController();
$web_ctlr->indexAction();
$web_ctlr->pageAction();
```

but the problem will be what are you doing inside your actions because the actions are meant for preparing a rendering. so I guess you will end up having multiple output especially if you are doing some html rendering in the controller constructor. If you are returning a valid data from your reusable actions then you should be ok for now. however I would suggest you to look at zend partial concept and decide which one suit your situation

Answer (score 0):

Actually the only thing you need is this (make sure you have the controllerDirectory setup in application.ini):

```
<?php
class App_Controller_Action_Helper_RequestForward extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    /**
     * @return null
     */
    public function direct($moduleName)
    {
        //this is basically the application.ini parsed & saved in Zend Registry
        $config = Zend_Registry::get('config');

        $controllersPath = $config->resources->frontController->controllerDirectory->$moduleName;

        $dispatcher = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getDispatcher();
        return $dispatcher->setControllerDirectory($controllersPath)->dispatch($this->getRequest(), $this->getResponse());
    }
}
```

and then in your controller from another module:

```
public function editAccountAction()
{
    return $this->_helper->RequestForward('default');
}
```